# How to prove the converge of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Let $t_{n} = \int_{1}^{n} (\ln(x)^p) \,dx$, where $p < 0$ is any real number.

How can I prove that this sequence converges?

My attempt: Clearly, $t_{n} \geq 0$, so by the linear property of Riemann integrals, $t_{n}$ is increasing. Then, if $t_{n}$ is bounded, it is also convergent. Can you find a bound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sequence does not converge. You are asking it $\int_1^{\infty}\ln(x)^pdx$ converges for any $p<0$, but for $p=-1$ we can use the comparison test with $\frac{1}{x}$ (i.e $\frac{1}{\log(x)}>\frac{1}{x}$) to see that the integral diverges since $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}dx$ diverges.

Comment: I see... Is that valid for the others $p < 0$? I mean $(ln(x))^p > 1/x$.

Comment: No: For any $p<0$ there exists a further (small) constant $c>0$ such that $\log^p(x)>\frac{c}{x}$. Thus, by comparison test with $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{c}{x}$ the series diverges.

Comment: The existence of such a constant $c$ can be seen from the fact that logarithms grow much slower that linear functions. If you want me to add another answer with a proof of this fact I can.

Comment: please!........

Answer (score 2):

An expansion on the discussion in the comments: For any $p<0$, we show that there exists some constant $c$ such that $\ln^p(x)>\frac{c}{x}$. We begin see that for any $N$ we have that

$$e^t=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}>\frac{t^N}{N!}$$

changing variables $x=e^t$ we get that

$$x>\frac{\ln^N(x)}{N!}$$

Thus,

$$\ln^{-N}(x)>\frac{1}{N!x}$$

and so the choice $c=[-p]!^{-1}$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes the least integer above its argument is a satisfactory choice.

Comment: Milo. Nice. N=1,2,3....